# javac: no source files

Tags: java, command-line

I tried to fix my problem with stack pages where the same problem but anything helps me.

Firstly, I changed the path :

```
cd C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\TASK 12 - Service Layer\src\main\java\com\foxminded\university\cli
```

In the package `cli` I have my `CheckSum.java`

Then I tried to

```
javac -classpath "C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\TASK 12 - Service 
Layer\src\main\java\com\foxminded\university\cli\CheckSum.java"
```

but I gain this :

```
javac: file not found: c:\home\files*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

In my System variables I have :

Path : D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

CLASSPATH : D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\lib

I checked if my file java exists in this package with command `dir` and I saw it here.

I will be appreciate for your help!

Thanks in advance.

When I am running javac CheckSum.java in necessary path, I receive :

```
CheckSum.java:3: error: package picocli does not exist
import picocli.CommandLine;

CheckSum.java:4: error: package picocli.CommandLine does not exist
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;

CheckSum.java:5: error: package picocli.CommandLine does not exist
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;

CheckSum.java:6: error: package picocli.CommandLine does not exist
import picocli.CommandLine.Parameters;

CheckSum.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
@Command(name = "checksum", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, version = "checksum 4.0",

 symbol: class Command
CheckSum.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@Parameters(index = "0", description = "The file whose checksum to calculate.")

symbol:   class Parameters
  location: class CheckSum
CheckSum.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
@Option(names = {"-a", "--algorithm"}, description = "MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, ...")

symbol:   class Option
location: class CheckSum
CheckSum.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
int exitCode = new CommandLine(new CheckSum()).execute(args);

  symbol:   class CommandLine
location: class CheckSum
8 errors
```

And the class `CheckSum.java` :

```
@Command(name = "checksum", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, version = "checksum 4.0",description = "Prints the checksum (MD5 by default) of a file to STDOUT.")
class CheckSum implements Callable<Integer> {

@Parameters(index = "0", description = "The file whose checksum to calculate.")
private File file;

@Option(names = {"-a", "--algorithm"}, description = "MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, ...")
private String algorithm = "MD5";

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    int exitCode = new CommandLine(new CheckSum()).execute(args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}

  @Override
public Integer call() throws Exception { // your business logic goes here...
    byte[] fileContents = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm).digest(fileContents);
    System.out.printf("%0" + (digest.length*2) + "x%n", new BigInteger(1, digest));
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The format for running javac on Windows is as follows:

`javac -cp path1;path2;path3 *.java`

where:

`path1` is the path to a directory or a jar file (**not** a java file or a class file), with libraries and such you use. For basic hello world, you would be using no such libraries, thus you don't need the classpath *at all*.

`path2` is similar; It's up there to show you that you have to use colons to separate them (semicolons on windows).

`*.java` is the source file(s) you want to compile.

Your command sets up a java file as the classpath (this does nothing), and then specifies 0 files for actual compilation, thus producing the error you observe.

The fix: to compile your `CheckSum` file when you've already cd-ed into that folder, all you need is:

`javac CheckSum.java`

no need for a classpath.

Comment: It didn't help. 
I added errors when I run javac CheckSum.java .
Checksum. java - is picocli class

Comment: It did help; you now get different errors. you want: `javac -cp path/to/picocli-version.jar *.java`

Comment: It helped, thanks!
But when I am trying to run this file from command prompt use command `java CheckSum.java`, I get the error : `Could not find or load main class CheckSum.java` 
Do you know why is it happened?

Comment: I added `CheckSum` to project, and it contains main

Comment: there is no such thing as a 'project' when invoking javac. To run java, you specify class names: `java -cp path/to/picocli-version.jar:path/to/where/your/compiled/classes/are CheckSum' <-- no .java at the end.

Comment: I wrote `java -cp D:\picocli-4.3.2.jar "C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\TASK 12 - Service Layer\src\main\java\com\foxminded\university\cli\CheckSum"` but have the same problem - could not load main.class

Comment: Read carefully: I said: You need to specify a -CLASS NAME-. So: java -cp "D:\picocli-4.3.2.jar;C:\Projectsblablabla\src\main\java\com\foxminded\university" cli.CheckSum   - that dir structure suggests it's a maven project, in which case, it's just 'mvn compile' and 'mvn run' once you have installed maven, by the way.

Comment: Successful compilation with `javac` resulted in a `CheckSum.class` file somewhere. The classpath should include the location of *this class* file (not the source file) when executing the program with `java`. Something like: `java -cp "D:\picocli-4.3.2.jar;C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\TASK 12 - Service Layer\build\classes" com.fixminded.university.cli.CheckSum`, assuming that the CheckSum class lives in a package named `com.fixminded.university.cli` and assuming that the `CheckSum.class` file exists in `C:\PROJECTS FOR FOXMINDED\TASK 12 - Service Layer\build\classes\com\foxminded\university\cli`.